# Scala does not read file from resources folder

Tags: scala, sbt, intellij-15

Why does the following not read the `war-and-peace.txt` file from the `resources` folder?

The folder structure in my project is the standard Scala structure that is created be Intellij.

For some reason it only reads this file when I put it in the `src/main/scala` (i.e. where my Scala code is), but ignores this file when I put it in the `src/main/resources` (in the latter case I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`, BTW I am getting the same exception also when I try to read `"/war-and-peace.txt"` (with a preceding slash) in case you were thinking to suggest it).

```
val file = new File(classLoader.getResource("war-and-peace.txt").getFile())

Source.fromFile(file).....
```

I am using

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

**build.sbt:**

```
name := "my-project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "resources"

libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.12"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4"
```

Comment: do not use `classLoader` use `getClass` (`getClass.getResource("/war-and-peace.txt").getFile()`)

Answer (score 12):

Use `getClass` not `classLoader`  and put `/` in front of the resource name `/war-and-peace.txt`. `war-and-peace.txt` file must be in resources folder (src/main/resources).

```
val file = getClass.getResource("/war-and-peace.txt").getFile()

Source.fromFile(file).getLines.foreach(println)
```

in one line

```
Source.fromFile(getClass.getResource("/war-and-peace.txt").getFile).getLines().foreach(println)
```

***getClass.getResourceAsStream*** is more reliable as it works when the code is packaged inside a jar file also

```
Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/war-and-peace.txt")).getLines().foreach(println)
```

Comment: I have tried similar suggestions that had been published in SO in the past. But I am still getting NullPointerException once I remove the input file from the `scala` folder and keep it only in the `resources` folder.

Comment: @rapt you did not read my answer carefully .. Use `getClass` not `classLoader`

Comment: @rapt have you tried `getClass` instead of `classLoader`. I have check it with my ide its working

Comment: Maybe you want to compare your build.sbt to mine. I had to downgrade some things there since I would get exceptions.

Comment: @rapt try again and removing this line `resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "resources"` from your `build.sbt`

Comment: @rapt you dont need this line in `build.sbt` `resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "resources"`

Comment: As expected removing or keeping resourceDirectory made no difference, since it's the default value. I only added it to undo Russian hackers.

Comment: i removed the "-" characters from the filename and it worked fine. did not look deeper to understand why :D

Answer (score -1):

I'm able to get the output by putting `dummy.txt` in `src/test/resources` and running a test case.

println(Source.fromResource("dummy.txt").getLines.length)